# Error when adding target to Swift/Obj-C project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I added a new target to my project (as a duplicate of the old one). The project loads fine, but as soon as I transition to the next view controller, I get a crash with "Could not find a segue class named xxxxxx."  This is also the first point the app encounters swift (the missing segue is written in swift).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add that class to your new target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this errors If we have multiple targets in project and when we add new files to project we miss that file to add to new targets.

So please check your new file for it's targets.

Click on your swift file (class with name xxxxxx as mentioned in error), open the `Identity inspector` and Check the `Target Membership` area. If your target is not selected there, select it.

[image: Identity Inspector]